# Array for-loop error

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I keep getting an error and I have no idea how to fix it.
The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Ch7Ex1NumberAboveAverage_TimmyHernandez.main(Ch7Ex1NumberAboveAverage_TimmyHernandez.java:35)
```

My code:

```
public class Ch7Ex1NumberAboveAverage_TimmyHernandez {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many temperatures do you have?");
        int entry = keyboard.nextInt();
        double[] temperature = new double[entry];

        System.out.println("Please enter the " + entry + " temperatures.");

        int index = 0;
        double total = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++);
        {
            temperature[index] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            total = total + temperature[index];
        }

        double average = (total / temperature.length);
        System.out.println("The average temperature is" + average + ".");

        System.out.println("The following temperatures are higher than the average temperature:");
        for (index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++);
        {
            if (temperature[index] > average);
            {
                System.out.println("Temperature " + (index + 1) + ":" + temperature[index]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please work on your class naming, I got scared for a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have a loop 
 `for (index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++);`

there is a semicolon at the end. Due to this, when loop ends `index` value is `temperature.length` and then on next line you re trying to access element beyond the array size. This is the common mistake/typo people do and hard to find in quick code walkthrough.

Change it to

`for (index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++)`

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` always give you the index value where your program was trying to access the array. By looking into line number and possible value of index, this kind of exception can be quickly rectified.

Comment: Wow I spent way too much time trying to figure out what I did wrong haha. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it happens. Going forward, work on coding standards and naming conventions for class, objects, variable etc.